# Exclude Literal backslash in Javascript Regular Expression

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'm writing a php forms class with client and server side validation. I'm having problems checking if a literal backslash ("\") exists in a string using regular expressions in javascript.

I want to shy away from solutions other than using regex as this will reduce the amount of special cases between php and js AND reduce the amount of conditional code I need to write.

I've just been using this as an example of what a user may need in this forms class-

> A password field that is a string
>   between 6 and 12 chars long and that
>   excludes "\","#","$","`"

I have tried:

```
^[^(\u0008#\$`)]{6,12}$
^[^(\b#\$`)]{6,12}$
^[^(\\#\$`)]{6,12}$
```

And none of them work for a backslash and I can't work out why. FYI: The latter works fine in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash. In JavaScript, this becomes `re = /\\/` or `re = new RegExp("\\\\")`.

ripped straight from http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Ah geez I'm a noob. I should of checked there first! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks to @Matthew Flaschen for catching something I didn't :| /facepalm

Comment: it's not you.  It's a weird bug in StackOverflow's renderer.

Comment: something tells me it does escaping with a regex of its own ... but I caught that I needed to make the other two blocks `\`` escaped

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've created a grouping of slash-hash-dollar-tick, rather than looking for any of those characters.

try this

```
var rgx = new RegExp(/^[^\\#\$`]{6,12}$/);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it wasn't the grouping. It was that I was encapsulating in quotes so either had to lose the quotes or escape as "\\\\". Appreciate your help. (S.O. just isn't letting me choose an answer yet :S)